# Wrapping a numpy array element to integer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, casting

I have a list of subgraphs that I am attempting to access within a loop:

```
 index=[5,3,4,1,1,3,4,2,3,4,2,2,3,3,2,4]
 subgraph=[[subgraph1],[subgraph2],[subgraph3],[subgraph4],[subgraph5]]
 for i in range(len(index)):
      for j in range(i+1,len(index)):
          if index[j]==index[i]
              continue
          testgraphi=copy.copy(subgraph[index[i]])
          testgraphj=copy.copy(subgraph[index[j]])
```

so in the first loop through, `testgraphi` would be assigned `subgraph5`, and `testgraphj` would be assigned `subgraph3`. However, when I attempt this method, I am returned an error `list indices must be integers, not numpy.float64`.  Which is logical, because `index` is ACTUALLY initialized as a numpy array in the full span of my program(and it must stay this way). So my question is, how can I cast this value so that it can be used as an index for my subgraph list? So that when `testgraph` is initialized, it will retrieve the value of index at which the loop is at, and use this to define which list index to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
new_index = np.asarray(index, dtype=np.int32)
```

This should cast all values in index into integer.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert `numpy.float64` to float by doing this: `var.item()`. Then convert it into an integer so you can use it as your index: `int(var.item())`